# Microsoft JScript runtime error: ASPx is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm getting this error all over the place in my web application and trying to figure out why.

The error is always for some control, ASPxClientTextBox for example. So far the only thing I've found as a potential fix is to check the httphandlers section of the .net web.config (the one in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config) and make sure an entry for "WebResource.axd" exists, which it does.

Any idea's what's going on or where I should look?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Turns out our web.config was missing entries for DevExpress assemblies as well as the DevExpress script module.

Comment: Hi Joe I am a having same issue so could you please share your web.config with highlighted area where you fix the issue.